# Datatable second page do not render

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using Datatable to render a table. The code is -

```
var nextPage;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "ordering": false,
    "serverSide": true,
    "sorting":false,
    "paging": true,
    "pageLength":20,
    "lengthChange" :false,
    "pagingType":"simple",
    "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
        data.nextPage=document.getElementById("nextPage").value
        $.ajax({url: "get/list", data: data, success: function(result){
            document.getElementById("nextPage").value=result.nextPage;
            callback(result);
        }});
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "first_name" },
        { "data": "title" },
        { "data": "first_name"  },
        { "data": "first_name" },
        { "data": "first_name" },
        { "data": "first_name" },
        { "data": "work_email" }
        ]

});
});
```

The first page loads fine when I open the page, but the second page keeps on loading. The /get/list API call succeeds for the second page but the data is not rendered on the browser and loading icon keeps on rotating.

Comment: Could you also include the JSON returns by the Ajax please

Comment: {
 "data": [{
  "title": "Mr.",
  "departmentName": null,
  "first_name": "Todd",
  "middle_name": null,
  "last_name": "lastName",
  "preferred_name": "name",
  "work_email": "hello@hello.com"
 }],
 "draw": 1,
 "recordsTotal": 100,
 "recordsFiltered": 100,
 "error": "",
 "nextPage": 12,
 "previousPage": 0
}

Comment: If that's the response for the second page, then that's the problem. 'draw' should be incrementing, so it should be 2 if it's the second response.

Comment: missing semicolon at the end of `data.nextPage=document.getElementById("nextPage").value`.